# Ansible getting list of files in folders containg special file

Tags: ansible, ls, xargs

I am trying to find the the files in side folders that contain 'done' file

i was trying to do it in pure ansible but i could not make it to work, so i am trying to do it using find,ls,xargs and then running it inside ansible shell command.

example for folders and file structure:

```
├── a12
│   ├── 1.txt
│   ├── 2.txt
│   └── 3.txt
├── a13
│   ├── 4.txt
│   ├── 5.txt
│   ├── 6.txt
│   └── done
└── a14
    ├── 7.txt
    ├── 8.txt
    ├── 9.txt
    └── done
```

and i am tring to get

```
4.txt
5.txt
6.txt 
7.txt
8.txt
9.txt
```

with the command

```
 find /tmp/test_an/ -type f -name 'done' | xargs dirname  | xargs ls -1 | grep -v 'done'
```

I am getting

```
/tmp/test_an/a13:
4.txt
5.txt
6.txt

/tmp/test_an/a14:
7.txt
8.txt
9.txt
```

i can exclude the folder using grep, but i am looking for a cleaner\better solution

Comment: Seems like the simplest solution of either using grep to only include the text files, or to exclude directory names is your best bet.  Or you could look at developing your own Ansible module (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules.html).

Comment: I am looking for a solution for something like that also, any progress?

Answer (score 1):

my best solution till now:

```
 find /tmp/test_an/ -type f -name 'done' | xargs dirname  | xargs -I{} find {}  -type f 

/tmp/test_an/a13/5.txt
/tmp/test_an/a13/4.txt
/tmp/test_an/a13/done
/tmp/test_an/a13/6.txt
/tmp/test_an/a14/8.txt
/tmp/test_an/a14/9.txt
/tmp/test_an/a14/7.txt
```